# How do I set a default filter on page load with footable v3?

Tags: jquery, footable

Looked up and down the web and couldn't find example code or instructions on how to do this with footable version 3. First look here: http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/examples/advanced/filter-dropdown.html

That is the code I'm working with and how my filter dropdown looks like. Instead of selecting "Any Status" by default, I want to select one of the other options by default. I can't change the following line to one of the other options, because that's not how that line works:

```
this.def = 'Any Status';
```

That line is to create a default entry that resets the filter.

I tried to manually select one of the option via jquery, which works, but it doesn't auto filter the table to the selected filter. It still shows all statuses. Below you will see how i am trying to re-trigger the table filter with those 2 commented out lines, but neither one works.

```
jQuery(function($){
    var text1 = 'Active'; //doing it with text because options don't have values
    $(".form-inline div select option").filter(function() {
        return this.text == text1; 
    }).attr('selected', true);
    //FooTable.components.core.register('filtering', FooTable.MyFiltering); //doesn't work
    //self.filter(); //doesn't work
});
```

Also, would still like the "Any Status" option to be there, which allows all rows with any status to show.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing to make it work. Just simulate a click on the search button.

```
jQuery(function($){
    var text1 = 'Active';
    $(".form-inline div select option").filter(function() {
        return this.text == text1; 
    }).attr('selected', true);
    $( "button.btn.btn-primary" ).click();
});
```